# mongodb can not create collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create collection in mongo, on the server running ubuntu

creating collection from the shell

```
db.createCollection('collName')

{
   "errmsg" : "exception: assertion util/mmap.cpp:169",
   "code" : 0,
   "ok" : 0
}
```

I tried to google about it but with no success.
Any ideas how to handle this?

PS. I am not out of space and I volume is writeable

Comment: Have you run out of disk space?

Comment: Is the directory that you set for Mongo to maintain data writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem
When mongo was just installed, one should have to create directories for its data

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

after this restart mongo

Comment: Is it good idea to create a central directory and give it to a special user? Shouldn't this be user-independent? Or otherwise reside in the user's home directory?

Comment: Very interesting. Even if they recommend it this is not a nice practice in Linux though.